# Would keyword lists make it easier for users to find what they need?

Tags: discussion

Belisarius has started a community wiki to document new user pitfalls. I wholeheartedly support this initiative. One thing I think would improve answers posted to this CW is having a list of keywords to aid the search engine in finding an appropriate answer. For example, I would like to add the following at the end of my recent post:

> **keywords** set assign ownvalue variable-binding

Is this a good idea?

#### update

I updated my [CW contribution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18456#18456) with keywords at the end of the answer. Since they're mainly for the use of search engines that where I think they belong.

Comment: can't we just retag the question? Or will there be too many tags to do this?

Comment: @Verbeia. If all goes well, I think there would be way too many tags, which is why I'm suggesting keywords,

Comment: I actually think this is a very good idea! It will make it appear in a lot more search results, both here and in Google

Comment: @m_goldberg - fair enough. In that case, I support the idea as well.

Comment: My initial intention was to set strict rules for "one answer, one topic". I decided it was too tyrannic and I let the ball rolling without much pressure on that side. After reading @Verbeia's excellent answers I got  convinced that that was the right thing to do.  Please suggest how to iplement "keywords lists" (in the index? in the posts?) ... Please consider that in a "near" future we could get more than one page of answers!

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to use the most important commands or built-in symbols appearing in the question and the answers as keywords. This could help people (including me) finding a solution when facing a problem with a certain command.